External USB disk wiped during loading of ISO on VMware Player 17.5.1 on Linux
I was loading an ISO image in VMware Player 17.5.2 on Linux, and in the lower right corner of the VM window, I guess I have chosen to make my external USB disk available to the VM.
So it was disconnected from my host OS and connected to the VM. And when an ISO was loading in the VM, it may have wiped all the contents of the external disk.
Is there a way to restore the data on the disk?

I'm afraid no !

Why do you say "may have"?  Do you not know if the external disk was wiped?  Or was it definitely wiped and you don't know what wiped it?  What was the ISO image?  Unless it was DBAN (or something similar), it seems a bit unlikely that it would have wiped the contents of your external disk (unless you explicitly did something to format or repartition it, mistaking it for a virtual disk).

There is no method that is faster, more complete or easier than restoring important data from one of your daily backups, even one of those physically rotated offsite.
Tools like ddrescue might recover some partial  data, but that might depend on filesystem type.
